# How do you create a composite unique constraint in db2

Tags: sql, db2

How do you create a composite unique constraint in db2.  I.e. so that the combination of both columns is unique.

Comment: `create unique index on the_table (column_1, column_2)`?

Comment: Many thanks. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table foo (
   bar int,
   baz int,
   unique(bar,baz)
);
```

Or, after the table is created:

```
create unique index on foo (bar, baz);
```